# How can i zip a complete directory with all subfolders in Java?

Tags: java, zip

Heyy! Before you go and report this as a duplicate: I researched for hours and hours and yes there are a LOT of sites, questions and videos about that, but none of those can help me.

I used diffrent techniques already to create a zip archive, which works great. I also get all files from subdirectories without a problem. But the thing is that i only get all the files listed, without their directories. If i have

> /something/somethingelse/text1.txt and /something/somethingother/lol.txt

I want it to be shown in the zip folder exactly like that.

In the zip folder there should be the 2 folders somethingelse and somethingother, containing their file(s). With all the versions i found, it puts all files and all files from other subfolders directly into the zip, so when i cliuck on the `.zip` it just shows `text1.txt` and `lol.txt`, without any folders.

Is there a way that processes a `.zip` as all the well-known programs for zipping files?

I just want to zip the directory and have everything as it was before, just packed into a zip archive.

I tried out everything i can with my level of java and also tried some online version, nothing leads to the result i want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here you go:

```
private static void zipFolder(Path sourceFolderPath, Path zipPath) throws Exception {
   ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipPath.toFile()));
   Files.walkFileTree(sourceFolderPath, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
       public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
           zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(sourceFolderPath.relativize(file).toString()));
           Files.copy(file, zos);
           zos.closeEntry();
           return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
    zos.close();
 }
```

./
[image: Zip]

./somethigelse/
[image: First folder]

./somethingother/
[image: Second folder]

Comment: Omg thanks! It worked perfectly, also that's a very short solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This solution preserves the hierarchy of the folder structure inside the zip file created -

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class ZipDirectories {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        zipDirectory(args[0], args[1]);
    }

    private static void zipDirectory(String zipFileName, String rootDirectoryPath) throws IOException {
        File directoryObject = new File(rootDirectoryPath);
        if (!zipFileName.endsWith(".zip")) {
            zipFileName = zipFileName + ".zip";
        }
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileName));
        System.out.println("Creating : " + zipFileName);
        addDirectory(directoryObject, out);
        out.close();
    }

    private static void addDirectory(File directoryObject, ZipOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        File[] files = directoryObject.listFiles();
        byte[] tmpBuf = new byte[1024];

        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                addDirectory(file, out);
                continue;
            }
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println(" Adding: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getAbsolutePath()));
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(tmpBuf)) > 0) {
                out.write(tmpBuf, 0, len);
            }
            out.closeEntry();
            in.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I referred to [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Makingazipfileofdirectoryincludingitssubdirectoriesrecursively.htm) link for the solution, and it works.